# XSLT Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

We are facing an issue where we are getting out of memory exception very frequently.
Here's the stack trace of the error that we get:

> Error occurred while generating request xml from facade class :
>   Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. at
>   (XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime,
>   XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current) at
>   Root(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime) at
>   System.Xml.Xsl.XmlILCommand.Execute(Object defaultDocument,
>   XmlResolver dataSources, XsltArgumentList argumentList, XmlWriter
>   writer) at System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform.Transform(XmlReader
>   input, XsltArgumentList arguments, TextWriter results)

On researching I found out that there may be 2 solutions to fix this one.

1. If you just load a stylesheet with a script once (you should avoid loading stylesheets in debug mode in production environment entirely) and re-use the object there will be only one assembly created
2. Compile the stylesheet “offline” (i.e. not at runtime) with the xsltc.

I have gone through the solution 2 and that does not fits into our system since we change our XSL quite frequently.

Now, the issue is I am unable to get a solution using the 1st method. 
So essentially I am looking forward to any hints that may lead me the way to "Re-use xslt file/object" in my system so that everytime I need not compile it when I need it.

Comment: As the problem is specific to your programming environment (.NET framework?) consider adding a tag for that as it looks you are looking for help in reorganizing your .NET code and not your XSLT code. Also note that you get the error on the `Transform` call, not on the call loading/compiling the stylesheet. So what kind of TextWriter is the transformation target, is that a StringWriter? Or are you writing to a file?

Comment: Transformation target is a stringwriter

Comment: If it is a StringWriter then I suppose your transformation result is too large.

Comment: You could try to write to a file instead, simply to test whether that way with the same input and same XSLT you don't run out of memory, that way you could identify whether it is writing to a StringWriter that causes the memory problems.